# Confirmation regarding touches on iPhone/iPad after inheritance?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following structure.

1. myBaseController : UIVIewController
2. myOriginalController : myBaseController

I have a few Views, ImageViews, Labels added on myOriginalController. I would like to have touches, which i get perfectly in myBaseController. Is there a way by which i get a static method or similar in myBaseController which receives an object and boolean parameter, to on or off the touches on the specific Object?

Say, I have a LabelA, for which i don't want to receive events, but i want to dynamically control the touches on objects and i would like myBaseController to manage that? So, in future if i could create myAnotherController which inherits myBaseController then also i would have turning on or off objects touches dynamically?

Please guide.

Thanks & Regards,
Reno Jones

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand exactly what you meant, but if you want to have a method to on or off touches in your BaseViewController you can write an instance method :

```
- (void) view:(UIView*)aView shouldReceiveTouch:(BOOL)receivesTouch {
// allow or block touch on aView
}
```

This method will be accessible to all instance object that are subclass from BaseViewController.

So in myOriginalController you can do :

```
[self view:self.label shouldReceiveTouch:NO];
```

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: Yes, similar stuff is what I am doing to turn on off touches but irrespective of ON/OFF, I keep on getting touches in Began,Moved, Ended methods of touch even if i set to off.

Comment: Then the problem comes from the way you are managing touches, it has probably nothing to do with your class hierarchy. You should update your question and provide the code from enabling and disabling the touches